# How to install my app to the android emulator

Tags: android

I know this is super trivial but please excuse the newbie.

So, I started the emulator with this command:

```
sudo /root/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none -force-32bit
```

I searched for my app there but could not find it.

Well, I think I should somehow install this app.

Then I tried this:

```
adb install /root/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp/app/build/outputs/apk/apk-debug.apk
```

then it showed this:

```
- waiting for device -
```

so, I thought I should relaunch the emulator and started it. When I did, that `adb` thing gave me this error:

```
rm: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would try Genymotion as I think installing apps on that emulator is super easy. Just drag and drop.

Also, it is faster than the android emulator that comes with Android Studios.

Comment: Thank you Simon :) I will def give it a try. I just started learning Android development today :) long way to go

Answer (score 0):

OK, doing `adb start-server` helped me